# Algorithm for Codility's Peak

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I have been trying to solve the `Peak` problem at Codility. What I came up with seems correct to me, but it fails one test and I cannot figure out what is wrong.

Problem (https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/10-prime_and_composite_numbers/peaks/)

> A non-empty array A consisting of N integers is given.
>
> A peak is an array element which is larger than its neighbors. More
> precisely, it is an index P such that 0 < P < N − 1,  A[P − 1] < A[P]
> and A[P] > A[P + 1].
>
> For example, the following array A:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 1
> A[1] = 2
> A[2] = 3
> A[3] = 4
> A[4] = 3
> A[5] = 4
> A[6] = 1
> A[7] = 2
> A[8] = 3
> A[9] = 4
> A[10] = 6
> A[11] = 2 has exactly three peaks: 3, 5, 10.
> ```
>
> We want to divide this array into blocks containing the same number of
> elements. More precisely, we want to choose a number K that will yield
> the following blocks:
>
> A[0], A[1], ..., A[K − 1], A[K], A[K + 1], ..., A[2K − 1], ... A[N −
> K], A[N − K + 1], ..., A[N − 1]. What's more, every block should
> contain at least one peak. Notice that extreme elements of the blocks
> (for example A[K − 1] or A[K]) can also be peaks, but only if they
> have both neighbors (including one in an adjacent blocks).
>
> The goal is to find the maximum number of blocks into which the array
> A can be divided.
>
> Array A can be divided into blocks as follows:
>
> one block (1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2). This block contains
> three peaks. two blocks (1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4) and (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 2).
> Every block has a peak. three blocks (1, 2, 3, 4), (3, 4, 1, 2), (3,
> 4, 6, 2). Every block has a peak. Notice in particular that the first
> block (1, 2, 3, 4) has a peak at A[3], because A[2] < A[3] > A[4],
> even though A[4] is in the adjacent block. However, array A cannot be
> divided into four blocks, (1, 2, 3), (4, 3, 4), (1, 2, 3) and (4, 6,
> 2), because the (1, 2, 3) blocks do not contain a peak. Notice in
> particular that the (4, 3, 4) block contains two peaks: A[3] and A[5].
>
> The maximum number of blocks that array A can be divided into is
> three.
>
> Write a function:
>
> function solution(A);
>
> that, given a non-empty array A consisting of N integers, returns the
> maximum number of blocks into which A can be divided.
>
> If A cannot be divided into some number of blocks, the function should
> return 0.
>
> For example, given:
>
> ```
> A[0] = 1
> A[1] = 2
> A[2] = 3
> A[3] = 4
> A[4] = 3
> A[5] = 4
> A[6] = 1
> A[7] = 2
> A[8] = 3
> A[9] = 4
> A[10] = 6
> A[11] = 2 the function should return 3, as explained above.
> ```
>
> Write an efficient algorithm for the following assumptions:
>
> N is an integer within the range [1..100,000]; each element of array A
> is an integer within the range [0..1,000,000,000].

My solution in Javascript is (https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingAQU25J-3N4/)

```
function solution(A) {
    // Implement your solution here

    const n = A.length;
    // prefix sums for peak count
    const peaks = new Array(n).fill(0);
    let peakCount = 0;
    // peak not possible at 0 and N-1 (only 1 neighbour)
    for(let i = 0; i < n; i++){
        if(A[i] > Math.max(A[i-1], A[i+1])){
            peakCount++;
        }
        peaks[i] = peakCount;
    }

    // if peakCount = 0 or 1 then that is the max
    if(peakCount < 2) return peakCount;
    


    const allBlockSizes = []; 
    for(i = 1; i <= Math.sqrt(n) + 1; i++){
        if(n % i === 0){
            allBlockSizes.push(...[i, n/i]);
        }
    }

    // blockSizes that produce blocks (blockCount) which have at least one peak/block
    let maxBlockCount = 0;

    for(const blockSize of allBlockSizes){
        if(blocksHaveAtLeastOnePeak(peaks, blockSize)) maxBlockCount = Math.max(maxBlockCount, n / blockSize);
    }

    return maxBlockCount;

}


function blocksHaveAtLeastOnePeak(peaks, blockSize){
    const blocksCount = peaks.length / blockSize;
    for(i = 0; i < peaks.length; i =i + blockSize){
    
        if(peaks[i + blockSize - 1] === peaks[i]) return false
    }
    return true
}
```

But it fails two specific tests - simple1 (got 2 expected 4) and large_anti_slow (got 18018 expected 30030). And I am unable to see what is wrong.

Comment: for starters, `for(let i = 0` doesn't look right - you can't have a peak at 0, as noted in the comment.

Comment: yes, why do you loop from `0` to `< n` instead of `1` to `< n - 1`?

Comment: I also cannot fathom the logic of your `blocksHaveAtLeastOnePeak` function, which you neglected to include in this question, and its `blocksCount` variable which is unused.

Comment: @DavidConrad I am sorry I did not understand your point about the function `blocksHaveAtLeastOnePeak` (it is included in the question). I just moved the logic to check the peaks in a different function. Is something wrong there. I am using divisors as `number of elements` in a block. Idea being the lower the number of elements in a block the higher the possible number of blocks.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I just didn't scroll down far enough before. But the logic escapes me. Also, the `blocksCount` variable is unused.

Comment: @DavidConrad @gog You are right. The loop can start with 1 instead of 0. However we do need to end the loop to `i < n` because without it the last element in the peaks array would be 0 and will fail all the tests that expect 1 as the answer. I did start the loop for 1 in my previous attempts but it does not change the results. It just uses one more loop (not saying I should use it).

Comment: @DavidConrad Let me add some debug comments. Please give me a few mins

Comment: if the loop goes to `< n` then you will try to access `A[i+1]` i.e. `A[n]` in array `A`, which should be an illegal operation. Apparently in Javascript it returns `undefined` and then `Math.max(x, undefined)` returns `NaN`, for some integer `x`.

Comment: @DavidConrad for some reason I am unable to edit the question now (says error saving). Here is a link to the solution where I start iterating from `i = 1` and have also added comments in the `blocksHaveAtLeastOnePeak` function. https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingGFJ7ZF-F7J/

Comment: @DavidConrad `Edit 2`. Now iterating to the upper bound of `n - 2` and manually adding the last element. Result is the same. Here is the attempt ( https://app.codility.com/demo/results/trainingE63384-TYK/ )